# Kafka Container stopped after sometime, Client Session Timedout

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i have one Zookeeper and 2 kafka brokers running in a docker environment. i am able to get the zookeeper and both kafka brokers up and running successfully (with producers/consumers able to connect and send/receive data) but after a while (maybe a day later), one of the brokers stopped. below are the last log of the stopped kafka server.

```
[2021-10-14 16:15:23,553] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-consumer-95901 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-35) (reason: removing member consumer-console-consumer-95901-1-66524e7c-561d-49f8-882e-93e5ee9732fa on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-10-14 16:15:23,553] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Group console-consumer-95901 with generation 2 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-35) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-10-14 16:23:09,577] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=2] Group console-consumer-95901 transitioned to Dead in generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-10-15 02:04:23,654] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 15654ms for sessionid 0x10005a177990003 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-15 02:05:35,005] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 15654ms for sessionid 0x10005a177990003, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

and these are the last logs from zookeeper

```
[2021-10-15 02:04:54,812] INFO Expiring session 0x10005a177990003, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-10-15 02:05:28,649] INFO Expiring session 0x10005a177990002, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-10-15 02:07:27,106] WARN CancelledKeyException causing close of session 0x10005a177990002 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2021-10-15 02:14:44,252] INFO Invalid session 0x10005a177990002 for client /172.18.0.3:36926, probably expired (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

i am not fully able to understand what happened, but it looks like broker wasn't able to communicate to the zookeeper anymore for some reason.

below is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1

    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://my-hostname-here:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M

  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1

    ports:
      - 29093:29093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://my-hostname-here:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M
```

below is the status of containers

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest not limiting the heap size of the brokers to only 512m, but you need to provide the logs of the stopped brokers

Comment: sure i can try increasing the server memory and then remove the 512 limit, first code snippet is the logs of the stopped broker, second are the logs of the zookeeper.

Comment: You should expect more warning and errors that actually say the broker is shutting down, not just Zookeeper client communication

Comment: that is all i have regarding the shutdown in zookeeper and broker logs

Comment: Those look like logs from kafka1 which is still running, not kafka2, then

Comment: Keep in mind that running two brokers on one host are competing for memory and the same disk, therefore will be slower than a single broker. Plus, your one host is still a single point of failure, and having any replication of data is therefore pointless

Comment: yes, totally agreed. this is just a test environment where i am trying to test a few things with multiple brokers. and nope, above are the logs of the broker which died.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `docker ps`, you see the exit code `137`

This is an OOMKilled code, which means the container needs more memory.

I suggest you remove `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` and let the JVM be limited to the container's full available memory space